# Apache pulsar / Pulsar Manager

Tags: apache-pulsar, pulsar

I have installed apache pulsar using helm chart in AWS EKS,
Reference : [Apache Pulsar Helm Deployment on Kubernetes](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/helm-deploy)

also enabled pulsar manager and deployed pulsar manager UI, all pods are up and running, when i open pulsar manager UI in browser using load balancer external IP, Manager UI is loading but unable to login using default username and password, also unable to get CSRF token

[Pulsar manager](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/administration-pulsar-manager/)

When i do curl, getting 404 not found error from pulsar manager
Pulsar manager : v0.3.0

```
CSRF_TOKEN=$(curl http://pulsar-load-balancer-ip:9527/pulsar-manager/csrf-token)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are there any errors in the logs?   Are the external IPs exposed?

what are the results of kubectl get nodes?

is everything running?

kubectl get pods -w -l app=pulsar

https://github.com/apache/pulsar-manager

he default values will create a ClusterIP for the Pulsar Manager you can use to interact with cluster. To find the IP address of the Pulsar Manager, use the following command:

kubectl get service -n 
After find the ip address of the Pulsar Manager, you can access the Pulsar Manager at http://${pulsar-manager-cluster-ip}/#/environments.

Answer (score 0):

The backend service may not complete starting for some reason
enter the container by command "kubectl exec" and see log

Answer (score 0):

after spending a couple of hours on this I got this working:

1. patch the deployment and remove the self-reference PULSAR_MANAGER_OPTS
2. add SPRING_CONFIGURATION_FILE: "/pulsar-manager/pulsar-manager/application.properties" to configData in values.yaml
3. by default the backend service works with HerdDB in in-memory mode, if you want your data to be persistent across pod restart (on a different node) / pod deletion you either change the application.properties (and mount to the pod ofc) and use HerdDB with zookeeper/bookie to store data or create statefulset with PVC and change application.properties to use JDBC driver.

also, I found that sometimes the backend gets OOM and the pod does not restart because it not running with pid 1, so it is worth checking this too.

also, the image is configured to run with root so some k8s distributions/cloud providers not allow runnig as root, in my case with openshift I had to add proper SCC